# USB Dongle Access in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Can someone please share a library/code to access a USB 3G dongle in C#..?

The library should support connecting/disconnecting and most importantly accessing the byte stream of data at Transport Layer (i.e. TCP/UDP packets with TCP/UDP header).

Thanks

Comment: I asked a question since I searched for it and couldn't find an answer. I registered in stackoverflow since I believed that it is somewhere people share their knowledge. But your rude answer makes me wonder otherwise. It is ok, if you don't know the answer but at least let someone who know the answer, answer it. Maybe the knowledge might be useful to you also someday.

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana be cool my friend. In-fact SO is not for such type of questions. Please read in faq section that What kind of questions can I ask here? and What kind of questions should I not ask here? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana For the question you asked. Devices connected with USB port send data on serial port. Using C# you can get that data but you will require the protocol definitions to decide the received bytes. It's only the manufacturer who can provide you such type of library you are asking for.

Comment: @hamad Thanks hamad. Now I get what you mean. I'll try and get a data sheet of my dongle from the manufacturer and that should provide me with the details I am looking for. Thanks a lot again.. :)

Comment: @BathiyaPriyadarshana You are welcome :) And if you delete this question, you can re-claim your points back.

Comment: @hamad Thanks for the information hamad :) Although I can gain the points by deleting the question, I won't, since the number of points/badges you gain doesn't reflect your knowledge and what you know and what you don't know. If this question reflects that I don't know something and in some people's viewpoint that I have asked a wrong question, so be it. The important thing is that, the question was 'a question' to me and there might be others who will have the same question. So I will leave this question which will be useful to any such person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every USB Dongle is different from each other that's why usually the company/manufacturer who developed your USB Stick will provide API to interact with it.

In our company also we are working on SafeNet/Alladin/Rainbow Parallel and USB Dongles for quite some years. We use them for security of our software. Which ever dongle we use, its the company which provides us its API.